# Use tuple as condition in pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

How would I use a tuple as the condition in the following rather than using a single value ("A" in this case):

```
df = df.query('ColA != "A"')
```

e.g.:

```
conditions = ('A','V','W')
df = df.query('ColA != "%s"' % conditions)
```

I want to pass in multiple conditions that vary in number so don't want to hard code the full query definition

Comment: try  `df.query('ColA not in @conditions')` . Convert to conditions = ['A','B','C'].

Comment: marvellous, thank you